# Nested function vs outer function with arrow function that passes event and parameters

Tags: javascript

I read that nesting functions when privacy is not needed is anti-pattern, because the inner function is created every time. So I am using requestAnimationFrame with current time to create a smooth scroll:

```
const smoothScroll = (y, duration, startPos) => {
    ...
    const scroll = (currentTime) => {
        ...
        if(timeElapsed < duration) return requestAnimationFrame(scroll);
    }
    requestAnimationFrame(scroll);
}
```

requestAnimationFrame is passing the current time, if I move it outside I need to pass the current time with an arrow function or create local variables:

```
const smoothScroll = (deg, duration, startPos) => {
    ...
    requestAnimationFrame((currentTime) => {
        scroll(currentTime, deg, duration, startPos) });
}
const scroll = (currentTime, startTime, deg, duration, startPos) => {
    ...
    if(timeElapsed < duration) requestAnimationFrame((currentTime) => {
        rotate(currentTime, deg, duration, startPos) });
}
```

So is this still considered anti-pattern with the current engine optimization and should I use the arrow function with parameters one if I don't need encapsulation?

Comment: The second would be preferential considering you now have both a generic `scroll` operation, as well as a `smoothScroll` operation - and as noted, you won't be recreating the `scroll` operation every time `smoothScroll` is invoked.

Comment: @lux Wrong. The first is actually more efficient, as it creates the `scroll` function only once and then reuses it in all `requestAnimationFrame` calls. The second snippet will recreate the `(currentTime) => {…}` anonymous function on every single animation frame.

Comment: @Bergi Wrong. In the first, scroll is created and assigned to `scroll` during every invocation of `smoothScroll `, and also offers the benefit of not locking the consumer into only using a single implementation of how to scroll the browser.

Comment: @lux I'm not talking about `scroll`, I'm talking about the extra arrow functions during 
a *single* invocation of `smoothScroll` - notice the recursion for the animation. And there's no "lock in", the `scroll` function is just an implementation detail of `smoothScroll` that you would hardly ever want to call directly. If you found a reason to reuse parts of the code (the `...` bits), you still could refactor by introducing helper functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I read that nesting functions when privacy is not needed is anti-pattern

Well, it might be an antipattern to nest function when it is not necessary<sup>1</sup>, but in your case it *is* necessary because of the closure access to the local variables. So just keep it as it is, there's nothing wrong with it.

<sub>1: keeping local variables private is one thing. Code structure might be another. You have to evaluate this against performance - creating functions is cheap, so unless it actually becomes a bottleneck there's no problem with nesting.</sub>